# Try to duplicate column= attribute1 at time=0 horizontally even on rows where time!=0 for every unique ID

Tags: join, ms-access, column-alias

Given a table such as this,

[image]

I want to create a table via SQL without doing window functions

| id | time | attribute1 | attribute1atFirstRecordedTimeperID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | a | a |
| 1 | 2 | b | a |
| 2 | 0 | c | c |
| 2 | 4 | d | c |

I tried

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    t1.time, 
    t1.attribute1,
    attribute1fixedattime0 = t2.attribute1
FROM s t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT attribute1 AS attribute1fixedattime0
    FROM s
    WHERE time = 0
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Is the column alias correct?

That throws an error[image]

If I fix this code, I want to make the SQL code work for the case when id=2 does not have their first attribute1 recorded at time t=0, but for t>0.
Then do I do a min on the join condition or inside the JOIN?

I want to create a table via SQL without doing window functions
to turn

into

To go from

| id | time | attribute1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | a |
| 1 | 2 | b |
| 2 | 42 | c |
| 2 | 69 | d |

to the table

| id | time | attribute1 | attribute1atFirstRecordedTimeperID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | a | a |
| 1 | 2 | b | a |
| 2 | 42 | c | c |
| 2 | 69 | d | c |

if you use a row_number() window function to mark the spot at which first time is within every id, then how do you join or would you not use a join but something else?

```
SELECT 
    id,
    time,
    attribute1,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) AS rn
FROM your_table

SELECT
    id,
    time,
    attribute1,
    FIRST_VALUE(attribute1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS attribute1atFirstRecordedTimeperID
FROM (
    -- Previous query here
) AS subquery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access a column `attibute1` from `t2`, but you gave this column the alias `attribute1fixedattime0`. So, use this alias:

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    t1.time, 
    t1.attribute1,
    t2.attribute1fixedattime0
FROM s t1
...
```

But I don't see the reason for this sub-select. You could join the table directly:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.id, 
    t1.time, 
    t1.attribute1,
    t2.attribute1 AS attribute1fixedattime0
FROM
    s t1
    INNER JOIN s t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.time = 0
```

However, this doesn't solve the problem. What you need is the minimum `time` value per `id`. Therefore create a SELECT with a GROUP BY:

```sql
SELECT id, MIN(time) AS time0
FROM s
GROUP BY id
```

We could also select `MIN(attribute1)`; however, I am not sure whether the attribute associated with the minimum time is also the minimum attribute. But we can get this attribute by doing another join:

```
SELECT tm.id, tm.time0, ta.attribute1 AS attr0
FROM
    ( SELECT id, MIN(time) AS time0
      FROM s
      GROUP BY id) tm
    INNER JOIN s ta
        ON tm.id = ta.id AND tm.time0 = ta.time
```

Now, we have the minimum time and its attribute per `id` and can do the final join to the original table:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.id,
    IIf(t1.time = t2.time0, 0, t1.time) AS [time],
    t1.attribute1,
    t2.attr0 AS attribute1fixedattime0
FROM
    s t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT tm.id, tm.time0, ta.attribute1 AS attr0
        FROM
            ( SELECT id, MIN(time) AS time0
              FROM s
              GROUP BY id) tm
            INNER JOIN s ta
                ON tm.id = ta.id AND tm.time0 = ta.time
    ) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Note that we use `Iff` to check for the row with the minimum time and then set the time to 0 even if it is not. I also put `[time]` inbrackets because it is a reserved word.